# Openshift Application Monitoring

Tags: cloud, openshift, visualvm, jconsole

I was wondering if it is possible to monitor java applications running on open shift

I am finding it next to impossible to remote connect via visual vm / jconsole (even with port forwarding) so i was unsure if there is another way to monitor performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use ssh tunnel with SOCKS proxy created via `ssh -D`. Once you have it, set the SOCKS proxy in VisualVM preferences. See [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/visualvm-monitoring-remote-jvm) article at DZone for detailed info.